# I would like to create a quiz game that picks random question from list without repetition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, random

**This code will let 2 players answer a random question from a list then compare their scores.**

Problems:

1. Questions keep repeating because of `randint`, tried using `random.shuffle` — no luck.
2. If I input an answer that is on the answer list on different questions it still printing "correct"
   maybe because of this code `if guess.lower() == answers[a].lower():`.
3. I can't make it work that if an answer is wrong it will print "wrong".
   I tried adding this code and it works, but if I input the correct answer it still returns "wrong".

```
elif guess.lower() != answers[a].lower():
    print("Wrong!")
    break
```

**My Code**

```
from random import randint
print("====== Quiz  Game ======")
print("")
questions = [
             "What star is in the center of the solar system?:",
             "What is the 3rd planet of the solar system?:",
             "What can be broken, but is never held?:",
             "What part of the body you use to smell?:",
             "How many days in one year?:",
             "How many letters in the alphabet?:",
             "Rival of Intel?:",
             "No.8 element on periodic element?:",
             "What is the galaxy that contains our solar system?:",
             "What animal is the king of the jungle?:"
             ]
answers = [
           "Sun",
           "Earth",
           "Promise",
           "Nose",
           "365",
           "26",
           "AMD",
           "Oxygen",
           "Milky Way",
           "Lion"
           ]

p1score = 0
p2score = 0
def playerOne():
    global p1score
    for i in range(5):
        q = randint(0,9)
        guess = input(questions[q])
        for a in range(len(answers)):
            if guess.lower() == answers[a].lower():
                print("Correct!")
                p1score += 1
                break
            else:
                continue
    print("Your score is:",p1score)
    print("")

def playerTwo():
    global p2score
    for i in range(5):
        q = randint(0,9)
        guess = input(questions[q])
        for a in range(len(answers)):
            if guess.lower() == answers[a].lower():
                print("Correct!")
                p2score += 1
                break
            else:
                continue
    print("Your score is:",p2score)
    print("")

def quiz():
    global p1score
    global p2score
    print("======Student no.1======")
    playerOne()
    print("======Student no.2======")
    playerTwo()
    if p1score > p2score:
        print("Student 1 has the highest score!")
    elif p1score < p2score:
        print("Student 2 has the highest score!")
    elif p1score == p2score:
        print("Students are tied!")
    else:
        print("Invalid")

quiz()
```

[Image of Problem no.1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBh5B.jpg)

[Image of Problem no.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rujy0.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: I would do it like this, create an empty list **seen_questions** and append the question inside the list, so every time you random pick a question check the **seen_questions** first if the question is already picked else print out the question. Make the a dictionary of questions and answers wherein keys=questions and values=answers.

Comment: you can use `random.shuffle(list)` at start - to get elements in random order - and later use only `for`-loop to get questions from this random list. But you would have to keep question and aswers together on one list - to shuffle them together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep question and answer together and then you can use `random.shuffle(list)` to create list with items in random order. And then you can use normal `for`-loop to get question and answer - and they will be in random order and never repeated.

You have question and answer together so there is no problem to check user's input with correct answer.

```
import random

data = [
  ["What star is in the center of the solar system?:", "Sun"],
  ["What is the 3rd planet of the solar system?:","Earth"],
  ["What can be broken, but is never held?:", "Promise"],
  ["What part of the body you use to smell?:", "Nose"],
  ["How many days in one year?:","365"],
  ["How many letters in the alphabet?:", "26"],
  ["Rival of Intel?:", "AMD"],
  ["No.8 element on periodic element?:", "Oxygen"],
  ["What is the galaxy that contains our solar system?:","Milky Way"],
  ["What animal is the king of the jungle?:",  "Lion"],
]

random.shuffle(data) # run only once 

for item in data:
    print('question:', item[0])
    print('  answer:', item[1])
    print('---')
```

---

**BTW:** you can write loop also this way

```
for question, answer in data:
    print('question:', question)
    print('  answer:', answer)
    print('---')
```

---

**EDIT:** Working code

```
import random

data = [
  ["What star is in the center of the solar system?:", "Sun"],
  ["What is the 3rd planet of the solar system?:","Earth"],
  ["What can be broken, but is never held?:", "Promise"],
  ["What part of the body you use to smell?:", "Nose"],
  ["How many days in one year?:","365"],
  ["How many letters in the alphabet?:", "26"],
  ["Rival of Intel?:", "AMD"],
  ["No.8 element on periodic element?:", "Oxygen"],
  ["What is the galaxy that contains our solar system?:","Milky Way"],
  ["What animal is the king of the jungle?:",  "Lion"],
]

# TODO: read data from text file or CSV file

def player(number, data):
    score = 0

    print("====== Student no.", number, "======")

    for question, answer in data:
        guess = input(question)
        if guess.lower() == answer.lower():
            print("Correct!\n")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Wrong\n")

    print("Your score is: ", score, "\n")

    return score

# --- main ---

random.shuffle(data) # run only once 
score1 = player(1, data)
#score1 = player(1, data[:5])

random.shuffle(data) # next player will have questions in different order
score2 = player(2, data)
#score1 = player(2, data[:5])

#score3 = player(3, data)  # you can have more players (but you could use list for scores)
#score4 = player(4, data)  # you can have more players (but you could use list for scores)
# best_score, best_player = max([score1, 1], [score2, 2], [score3, 3], [score4, 4]) 
# results_in_order = sort( [[score1, 1], [score2, 2], [score3, 3], [score4, 4]], reverse=True ) 


if score1 > score2:
    print("Student 1 has the highest score!")
elif score1 < score1:
    print("Student 2 has the highest score!")
else:
    print("Students are tied!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help you almost did it all, I'm still comparing and trying to understand your code on how you make it work just fine, btw I am new to python, thanks for the new knowledge.

Comment: is it possible to put a range on how many questions you only have to answer, like i only need 5 questions and not to answer the 10 questions, like how `sample.random` works

Comment: `for item in data[:5]` ?

Comment: or you could change function `def player(number, data)` so you would run `player(1, data[:5])` , `player(2, data[5:])` - so player 1 gets first 5 question, and player 2 gets other 5 questions. It would need only one `shuffle` to use different question for evey player.

Comment: It works now, after removing the other `random.shuffle`

Answer (score -3):

## 9. Write a simple quiz game that has a list of ten questions and a list of answers to those questions.

## The game should give the player four randomly selected questions to answer. It should

## ask the questions one-by-one, and tell the player whether they got the question right or

## wrong. At the end it should print out how many out of four they got right.

```
question_prompts = [

["What color are apples?\n(a)Red/Green\n(b)Orange \n(c)Violet/Green\n(d)Black/Orange", "a"],

["What color are bananas?\n(a)Red/Green\n(b)Yellow \n(b)Orange \n(a)Violet/Green", 'b'],

["What Month is Christmas?\n(a)September \n(b)December \n(c)October \n(d)November", 'b'],

["What color are Rice?\n(a)Red/Green\n(b)Yellow\n(c)Red/Green\n(d)Yellow", 'b'],

["What animal can run faster than Lion?\n(a)Man\n(b)Dear\n(c)Red/Green\n(d)Yellow", 'b'],
     
["How many continents in the World ?\n(a) Seven\n(b) Nine\n(c)Red/Green\n(d)Yellow", 'a'],

["How many colors rainbow has?\n(a)Seven\n(b)Five\n(c)Red/Green\n(d)Yellow", 'a'],

["What is my name?\n(a) Nick\n(b)Chioma\n(c)Tiger\n(d)Greatness", 'a'],

["What year did Pandemic occur?\n(a)2020\n(b)2019\n(c)2021\n(d)2023", 'a'],

["How old is the earth approximately?\n(a)6b years\n(b)6.4b years\n(c)6b years\n(d)6.4b years", 'b']


]

count = 0


sample = sample(question_prompts, 4)

for i, j in sample:

    print(i)

    answer = input("Enter your answer: ").lower()

    if answer == j:

        count += 1

        print("Right, Your score: ", count)

        print('')

    else:

        print("Wrong, correct answer is: ", j)

        print()

print("You got", count, "out of", len(sample), "questions")
```

This works for me.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30705765)